# Determine whether a list is a reordering of another

Tags: list-manipulation

For some context: I have a function `Prod[a___,state]` which represents a list a___ of quantum mechanical operators acting on a state. After manipulating the elements in a___, I end up with a sum of products of  operators. For example, I get `c_1*Prod[P1,P2,state] + c_2*Prod[P2,P1,state]`, where P1 and P2 commute. I am looking for a way to directly obtain the coefficient `c_1+c_2`. To do so:

I am trying to define a bilinear function `Dot[Prod[a___,state],Prod[b___,state]]` that would return 1 if a___ is a reordering of b___ and 0 otherwise.

I know how to make my function bilinear, but I have no idea how to specify the condition of "a is a reordering of b".

Note that P1 can appear multiple times, which prevents me from simply using Complement[].

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: If `Prod` is not itself commutative (that is, some but not all operators commute with one another) then one could use `Sort[{a}]===Sort[{b}]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare `prod` `Orderless`, and then use `Simplify` to obtain the result:

```
SetAttributes[prod, Orderless]
c1 prod[P1, P2, state] + c2 prod[P2, P1, state] // Simplify
```

> `(c1 + c2) prod[P1, P2, state]`

I'm not sure I follow your idea for how to extract the coefficient, but perhaps something like this:

```
prod /: Times[a_prod, b_prod] := If[a === b, 1, 0]
Sqrt[sum sum]
```

> `Sqrt[(c1+c2)^2]`

Also see the comment by Michael E2 on how to make sure that `state` is not mixed up with the orderless parameters.

Comment: By my reading of the OP, `state` has to come last — at least it is distinguished by being a state and not an operator.  `Orderless` cannot guarantee it comes last.  I think the syntax would have to be changed to `prod[P1, P2,...][state]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 thank you, I added a pointer to your comment in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
(c1 prod[P1, P2, state] + c2 prod[P2, P1, state]) /. p_prod :> Sort[p] // Simplify
```

> ```
>   (c1 + c2) prod[P1, P2, state]
> ```

If `prod` is orderless only in the first two arguments, you can do:

```
(c1 prod[P1, P2, state] + c2 prod[P2, P1, state]) /. 
  prod[a_, b_, st_] :> prod[## & @@ Sort[{a, b}], st] // Simplify
```

> ```
> (c1 + c2) prod[P1, P2, state]
> ```

or

```
(c1 prod[P1, P2, state] + c2 prod[P2, P1, state]) /. 
  prod[OrderlessPatternSequence[a_, b_], st_] :> prod[a, b, st] // Simplify
```

> ```
> (c1 + c2) prod[P1, P2, state]
> ```